# Bootstrap navbar li class="dropdown" not showing

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I have added on my site a collapse navbar:
The matter is the li class dropdown don't show, when I inspect it, I see width and height 0px but even inf I change it in the inspector the li doesn't appear...

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>                        
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="#home">Accueil</a></li>
            <li><a href="#service">Le Service</a></li>
            <li><a href="#portfolio">Notre r&Eacute;seau</a></li>
            <li><a href="#about">Qui sommes nous?</a></li>
            <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown">
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <form id="login">
                    <li><input class="form_login" type="text" id="email" placeholder="e-mail" /></li>
                    <li><input class="form_login" type="password" id="password" placeholder="mot de passe" /></li>
                    <li><button class="form_login" id="submit" value="submit">Submit</button></li>
                </form>
                <li><a href="#" style="color: white;">Mot de passe oublié?</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" style="color: white;">Créer un compte</a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><span class="icon-facebook"></span></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><span class="twitter-square"></span></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><span class="google-plus"></span></a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
```

The only css is:

```
    .dropdown-menu{
    background-color: #181A1C;
    padding: 3px;
    border: 1px solid #181A1C;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have several things going wrong. First, you don't have an anchor set up to trigger the dropdown. **[See the docs](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar)**.

```
<li class="dropdown">
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Contact <span class="caret"></span></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
```

Then, you have invalid list markup. You cannot wrap list item elements with a form. **[Here's a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/7g53wukp/)** with most of the fixes in place. You'll need to work your form inside the dropdown list item, not around it. Use an additional level of list if necessary.

Comment: This worked on a previous version of my site...then I changed something and login li messed up...